# Why are PNG deflate-block lengths being ignored?

Tags: compression, png, zlib, libpng, deflate

**Summary:** I need a PNG writer and for various reasons I had to make it from scratch. I don't need to compress the image data, so I implemented PNG using the no-compression deflate algorithm. Rendering fails for images requiring multiple deflate blocks, seemingly because it ignores block lengths.

**Issue:** When I have a tiny image written with a single deflate block, the resulting image is exactly what it is supposed to be (all pixels correct, no errors when checked with [pngcheck](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/pngutils.htm)). However, as soon as I use multiple deflate blocks the resulting image is wrong because deflate blocks are being read past their lengths (though pngcheck still shows no errors). Looking at the raw data in a hex editor seems to show that everything is to spec (according to [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/png-1.2-pdg.html), RFC 1950, and RFC 1951).

**Example Data:** I generated a 3x1 RGBA image where the pixel colors are, from left to right, `(fb,02,03,fa)`, `(01,fc,03,fa)`, `(01,02,fd,fa)`. I then wrote them to file with either an 8-byte or 64-byte maximum deflate block length. The 64-byte block length image is exactly correct and renders properly.

Complete image contents follow, as hex, where bold are the block lengths and italics are the block data.

*8-byte block image* (renders incorrectly):
`89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 08 06 00 00 00 1b e0 14 b4 00 00 00 1d 49 44 41 54 78 9c 00`**00 08**`ff f7`*00 fb 02 03 fa 01 fc 03*`01`**00 05**`ff fa`*fa 01 02 fd fa*`05 ee ac ee a1 e1 2d b9 00 00 00 00 49 45 4e 44 ae 42 60 82`

*64-byte block image* (renders correctly):
`89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 08 06 00 00 00 1b e0 14 b4 00 00 00 18 49 44 41 54 78 9c 01`**00 0d**`ff f2`*00 fb 02 03 fa 01 fc 03 fa 01 02 fd fa*`05 ee ac ee f8 dc a0 6c 00 00 00 00 49 45 4e 44 ae 42 60 82`

The beginning of each deflate block consists of 5 bytes: 0 or 1 (depending on if it's the final block) followed by a 2-byte length (in bold above) and its 2-byte one's complement. In the 8-byte block image, the length for the first block is 8 just as it should be. The 8 bytes after the length complement (in italics above) are indeed the values they are supposed to be, and the 9th byte equals 1 (and starts the final block). However, that 1 is being interpreted as a color value (the alpha for the second pixel) instead of as the start of the next block!

Presumably there is something that I'm missing about the structure of deflate blocks. Am I being dumb and making a mistake, or did I misunderstand the specs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both PNG files are invalid, even though one happens to render correctly (and even though pngcheck doesn't catch it).  They both do not properly terminate the embedded deflate streams.

Looking at one of the deflate streams, the stored lengths and complements are big-endian instead of little endian.  E.g. instead of `00 0d ff f2` it needs to be `0d 00 f2 ff`.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I have a suspicion that my Adler32 implementation is wrong so that the stream checksum is incorrect. Perhaps that would that prevent the streams from terminating?

Comment: Yes, the Adler-32 is also wrong, but your problem is being caused by the swapped stored lengths.  The PNG renderer is apparently ignoring the Adler-32 error anyway.

Comment: I thought those lengths were in the wrong byte-order, but when I swapped them I got an error. Probably that means it was then able to successfully get to the **other** error. Pretty sure this will be the fix. Will fix the byte order and the Adler32 and mark resolved if so. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, it was the combo of byte-order and bad checksum that was the problem. Also just realized that you are _that_ Mark Adler. Now I'm extra embarrassed for implementing a broken version of that simple checksum algorithm...